# How to change the status bar notification icons' color/tint in android (marshmallow and above 23+)?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

As the title says, how do I change the status bar icons' color to have a dark tint instead of the default white.

**FROM**

[image]

**TO**

[image: dark status bar]

Answer (score 77, accepted):

For the status bar icons' to have a dark tint instead of the default white, add the following tag in your `styles.xml` (or more precisely in `values-v23/styles.xml`) file:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
```

You can also change the flag at runtime by setting it to any `View`:

```
View yourView = findViewById(R.id.your_view);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (yourView != null) {
        yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
}
```

If you want to reset the changes, clear the flag like this:

```
yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
```

Comment: If you use the programatic method of setting the light status bar, is there a way to change it back to the regular dark version?

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may try recreating the `View` itslef on which the flag was set. For me, I just recreate a `Fragment` when a preference is changed.

Comment: <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>

Comment: To change it back to dark:  
`rootView.setSystemUiVisibility(rootView.getSystemUiVisibility() & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);`   Unfortunately this causes a noticable redraw flicker for me, any suggestions for that appreciated.

Comment: Why is this method called on a View? What is yourView in this case? Anyone got any insights?

Comment: what if api level before 23 ?

Comment: @DharaPatel with the given code, it'll be just a `no-op` in previous versions of android.

Comment: any other solutions for previous version?

Comment: @DharaPatel there isn't any. Previous versions of android do not support status bar tinting (light/dark modes).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the `Activity`'s theme is set to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: @AdamJohns I use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` and the above code works just fine.

Comment: I use toolbar as the view, but this does not seem to work. Any hint?

Comment: @Sermilion Try using `getWindow().getDecorView()` from your `Activity`

Answer (score 2):

Below is sample code, change status bar color when switch between portrait&landscapse. portrait mode : light bar, dark icon; landscape mode : dark bar, light icon; Theme: "Theme.AppCompat.Light"

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Window window = getWindow();
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        if(Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE == newConfig.orientation) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000")); // set dark color, the icon will auto change light
            }
        } else {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE|View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#fffafafa"));
            }
        }
    }
```