# Invert icon color of status bar

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I have searched a lot about this but all I have found is how to change status bar color.
I want to invert color of icons in status bar on white background like [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com) has done in its mobile application like:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do that with the following code. it's just working on `v23 API`.

In your: `values-v23/styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075921/4409113

Or: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33316669/4409113

Comment: Thank you, I just figured out.

Comment: No problem, anytime :)

Comment: Is there a backport for pre API v23?

Comment: It does not work for me. Is there any special theme I must use for that to work?

Comment: I use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and it works.