# Android: How to remove ActionBar without making Status Bar unreadable

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-statusbar

I'm new to android and one of my activities does not require the Action Bar but I'd like to keep the Status Bar. I have this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

This removes the Action Bar as expected and the Status Bar is there but now it's unreadable (white icons on an off-white background). How can I fix this? I'd be fine with changing the background of the Status Bar to black. Minimum SDK 19

Answer (score 2):

For everyone looking for a solution, here's one :

In your styles.xml add this :

```
<style name="AppTheme.OnlyStatusBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>
    </style>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml, for the choosen activity, add this :

```
<activity
            ...
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.OnlyStatusBar">
           ...
</activity>
```

It will be showing the windows without any action Bar and still with the status bar.
That's all, ez pz :) !

Answer (score 1):

That is normal because the background is light and it's like a `FullScreen Activity` and the icons or other things are not readable.

In the new android, there is a new feature to do that(in `values-v23/styles.xml`):

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

**See:** [How to change the status bar notification icons' color/tint in android (marshmallow and above 23+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316668/how-to-change-the-status-bar-notification-icons-color-tint-in-android-marshmal)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using `Android Studio`, nowadays you have an option to create `FullscreenActivity`, that it doesn't include the `ActionBar`:

```
File -> New -> Activity -> Fullscreeen Activity
```