# Status bar icons and text tint in Android versions < 23

Tags: android

The default tint of status bar in Android is white(so it some kind of soppos that status bar will be dark):
[image]
[I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316668/how-to-change-the-status-bar-notification-icons-color-tint-in-android-marshmal) that I can change tint in Android versions greater or equal to 23.
But then I found out that several apps on my device(Android 5.1, API 22) use black tints. How did they did it?

**Update:**
This is what I mean:
Some other App have light status bar and black icons, time label and so on.

[image]

This is my App sample with white status bar:

[image]

I can't set `windowLightStatusBar` as true to make it looks like app from first picture in devices with API < 23.

Comment: setStatusBarColor was added in 21, not 23.  So they're using that on your phone.

Comment: @GabeSechan setStatusBarColor can only set color of my statusBar, not tint of it's icons. So there will be white status bar with white icons and text on it(case I have at this moment).
To turn on dark tint you have to use windowLightStatusBar (API 23)

Comment: You're going to have to show some screenshots because afaik what you ask is not possible by standard means.

Comment: @EugenPechanec . Add pictures to make it more clear.

Comment: A standard way would be to compile against the [Android SDK extension] provided by your phone's vendor. And that would limit your app only to devices which have that SDK extension. You'll probably want to focus on more important issues than this.

Answer (score -1):

For API level < 23, Add this to your activity for dark icons on a light background:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
View view = window.getDecorView();
setLightStatusBar(view, this);
```

Then create a function setLightStatusBar that will show dark icons on a light background:

```
public static void setLightStatusBar(View view, Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            int flags = view.getSystemUiVisibility();
            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR;
            view.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

            // You can change the background color of the status bar here
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
```

For API level 23 and above, simply add this to your styles

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Texts and background are still both white. Any way to change the text to black>

Answer (score -2):

You can use this method to give a statusBar your own color in kitkat and lollipop and above devices

```
public void translucentStatusBar() {

            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }

            View view = findViewById(R.id.vFakeStatusBar);
            view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_status_bar_height)));
        }
```

In above code snippet view in the statusBar of height 24dp(default).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I meant color of text, icons, battary time, etc. Not color of status bar exactly.

Answer (score -3):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316668/how-to-change-the-status-bar-notification-icons-color-tint-in-android-marshmal) answer, add in `values-v23/style.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: This works great, but you should device with API >= 23 to use it.
I just found several apps on my device(API=22) which can use this feature.