# Show white status bar with black icons below Marshmello

Tags: java, android, icons, android-5.0-lollipop, statusbar

I want to show the status bar as white and icons as black. For this I checked solutions on SO for Marshmello.

[How can I make the status bar white with black icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623627/how-can-i-make-the-status-bar-white-with-black-icons)

[How to change the status bar notification icons' color/tint in android (marshmallow and above 23+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316668/how-to-change-the-status-bar-notification-icons-color-tint-in-android-marshmal)

Used     `<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>` this in theme but this only works marshmello and above it.

Also tried this:

[How to set Status bar to white background and black text (black icon) in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080449/how-to-set-status-bar-to-white-background-and-black-text-black-icon-in-my-app)

How to achieve this below marshmello?

Please help thank you..