# How to change StatusBar colour android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-theme

No matter what I try within themes I cant seem to change the colour of the status bar from this grey colour:

[image]

Here is my themes file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.AlarmClockProject" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I have tried multiple variations of this, removing some of these etc..

I have tried changing the `colorPrimary/variant` etc to no avail.

[I found this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316668/how-to-change-the-status-bar-notification-icons-color-tint-in-android-marshmal) that says to use the `values-v23/styles.xml`
but this seems outdated as I have no `styles.xml`, now it is themes and this line is included above anyway.

target/compileSDK is 32, minSDK is 23

Comment: `<item name="android:statusBarColor">#FF000000</item>`changes the color of the status bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your custom color to `themes.xml` and also don't forget to add in the `night\themes.xml` file. Otherwise, your status bar color shows the default color in `DarkMode`.

path-1:- res>values>themes>`themes.xml`

path-2:- res>values>themes>`night\themes.xml`

add your custom color to `primaryVariant`

```
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/my_color</item>
```

and then add the below line in your colors.xml

path:- res>values>`colors.xml`

```
<color name="my_color">#888888</color>
```

here this code is `#888888` for gray. You can add your custom color code here.

**EDIT-1**

set `Statusbar` color `Programmatically`

Add the below code to your `activity` inside the `onCreate` method.

```
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.black)); // here is your color
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I have "<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>" in both dark and night themes and still only get grey? could there be something else blocking this somewhere?

Comment: @JoePleavin can I see your new code of `"colorPrimaryVariant"`?

Comment: It's currently just @color/white as above.. do I *have* to make a custom colour? I'll try it now.

Comment: @JoePleavin yes first try my answer. If not woks let me know.

Comment: no, no change. its exactly teh same as in the picture I posted above.

Comment: @JoePleavin checkout updated code in my answer.

Comment: I can't edit your answer, but add this in as a line: `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR` this changes the icons in thetop bar to black, so if you change the bar to white you can still see them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    res-> values-> themes.xml
    
     <style name="Theme.AlarmClockProject" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/white</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
            <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/green_color</item>
          
        </style>


colors.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="purple_200">#FFBB86FC</color>
    <color name="purple_500">#FF6200EE</color>
    <color name="purple_700">#FF3700B3</color>
    <color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>
    <color name="teal_700">#FF018786</color>
    <color name="green_200">#57CC75</color>
    <color name="black">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: my minimum sdk is 23 so adding target api doesnt need to be there. I cant understand why nothing is working, copying your code into my file does nothing.